# Download image from url and save in sd card folder in flutter

Tags: flutter, path, filepath

I want to download an image from URL and save it into the SD folder.

what I have tried:

I have tried this code it works fine but it store in
`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.college_services/files/Images`
but i want to store in `/Sdcard/Images`

```
_dowloadimg() async{
    var url = widget.imageURL;
    var response = await get(url);
    var documentDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    var firstPath = documentDirectory.path + "/Images";
    var filePathAndName = documentDirectory.path + '/Images/img_${i++}.jpg';
    await Directory(firstPath).create(recursive: true);
    File file2 = new File(filePathAndName);
    file2.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);

  }
```

Comment: you are using path_provider_package which won't provide you the download directory path

Answer (score 0):

As path_provider doesn't provide download directory path. You will need to call native apis.

Use These packages to do that:-

[downloads_path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/downloads_path_provider)
OR
[ext_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/ext_storage)

In case of 1st one the code will look like this:-

```
var documentDirectory = await DownloadsPathProvider.downloadsDirectory;
```

In case of 2nd one the code will look like this:-

```
var documentDirectory = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

Comment: can we create a folder inside downloads directory?